# Do Android apps have access to Facebook credentials?

Tags: android, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

If I write and distribute an Android app which uses the Facebook API to log in and share content, are the user credentials accessible from my app code, or is the Facebook API protected - for example by using a separate module (authentication helper, called over an Intent)?

Or, in other words: can I choose to present user name / passwort input fields in my app, and then transfer the user input to the Facebook server to authenticate (and receive an access token), or will the Facebook SDK for Android itself present a protected login dialog, and only return authentication status and access token to my app?

Comment: without credentials you have limit access to facebook api , when you have any use id you will know his name , URL  , if you need more , you need to request  it from facebook

Comment: Please see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1) helps you

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to utilize the Graph API, you'll want your users to log in with Facebook.  Facebook has provided a lot of documentation on setting up Facebook login for websites, mobile (in your case), etc.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1

I don't program with the SDK for Android, but it probably follows the same flow as a web application.  User's will click on a log-in button within your application which will prompt them to log in (obviously) but also ask for any permissions you might need for your app to function.  If you set up your login code correctly, you will be able to verify and authenticate the user to ensure they are actually a real person using Facebook.  Once a user is logged in, you will gain access to the the user's access token which you can use to make API calls (some public functions don't require the user access token, but you can read more about that in the documentation).